# Compare results in a for loop c++

Tags: c++, loops, compare

My assignment is essentially to ask the user "how many numbers do you want to enter" then if the user, for example, enters 2 number it says which is the highest number. What I'm having trouble with is comparing those numbers since they are in a loop.

```
cout<<"how many #s do you want to enter?"
cin>>number;
for(int i=1; i<=number; i++){
    cout<<"Input number: ";
}
if ( **first number** > **second number**)
    cout<<"First number is bigger";
else 
    cout<<"Second number is bigger";
```

Is it possible to compare the numbers that result in the loop? If not, is there a simple way to do a process similar to this?

Comment: push_back the numbers to a std::vector, then use std::max_element on the vector.

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want to output the maximum number of all *n* numbers input by a user? If yes, you can compare in the loop each input number with intermediate max number of previously input numbers and output the max after loop finished.

Comment: You can do a lot inside the for loop. For example, you can get a number from the user. If it's bigger than the biggest number you've ever seen, you can set it as the new biggest number.

Comment: Keep track of the biggest number you have currently seen. Then, in the input loop, if the user entered a bigger number than the largest one you have seen, update it. You can initialize the variable storing the largest number to a very small value so it the first iteration always updates it.

Comment: You could also consider using a loop construct other than `for`.   There are also `while` and `do`-`while` loops.

Answer (score 1):

Your question wasn't very clear, but I'll guess you want a code that returns the greatest number that the user entered. As someone suggested in the comments, you can keep track of the greatest in each iteration:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int how_many;
    cout << "How many #s do you want to enter?" << endl;
    cin >> how_many;
    int max_so_far = 42; // Ha
    for (int i = 0; i < how_many; i++) {
        int input;
        cout<<"Input number: ";
        cin >> input;
        if (i == 0 ||  input>max_so_far) {
            // if it's the first number or it's greater than max_so_far
            max_so_far = input;
        }
    }
    cout << "The biggest number was " << max_so_far << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the variable 'max_so_far' holds nothing important in the first iteration (no number was yet seen). You can check if it's the first iteration, as I did, or you can initialize 'max_so_far' a minus infinity (lowest number you can represent on that type, an 'int' in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your comparison occurs outside the for-loop; you should move it inside the loop to compare all the numbers.

Secondly, you are not even saving the user input. You want to create a variable `max`, for example, and set it to zero. Then, in the for-loop, compare every input value to the value in `max`, and if it is bigger, then set `max` to that value.

And to answer your question, yes, you can compare numbers that result in a loop or nest of loops *inside* the loop.